# Getting the padding in pixels, from an element with the value originally assigned as percentage

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a div with left padding assigned with percentage, as follows:

```
padding-left: 1%;
```

And after resizing the window, I need to get the value in pixels, to make some computations. Using Javascript `element.style.paddingLeft` I get the original String "1%". ¿How can I get the real padding assigned in percentage but in pixels?

I can't edit the main CSS file, so changing the units from % to px is not an option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do some maths since you can get the width of the window by using `window.innerWidth`.

```
let yourPadding = (document.getElementById("yourDiv")element.style.paddingLeft * window.innerWidth)/100;
```

Comment: yes @EduDev, your approach works and answer my question, but after some additional tests, I opted to use computed = getComputedStyle(element) and  parseFloat(computed.width), which does not need additional computations.